# Error: name lookup of ‘x’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I am trying to compile my code i am getting the following error:

```
error: name lookup of ‘x’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping [-fpermissive]
note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)
```

Can any body please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

```
int main() {

  int a,m;

  cout << "Enter values of a and m:" << endl;
  cin >> a >> m;
  a %= m;

  for(int x = 1; x < m; x++) 
  {
    if((a*x) % m == 1) 
      return x;
  }

  cout << "the value of x" << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your `x` declared only within loop, and you're trying to use it even outside of loop (last line with `cout`). Compiler don't really like it.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `x` is limited to the for loop since you declared it there. If you want to use it outside, declare it in the appropriate scope as follows:

```
int main() {

           int a,m;

           cout << "Enter values of a and m:" << endl;
           cin >> a >> m;
           a %= m;
           int x; 
           for(x=1; x < m; x++) 
            {
              if((a*x) % m == 1) 
              return x;
            }

          cout <<"the value of x"<<x<<endl;

}
```

Comment: i am not able to get any output for X, what may be the problem.

Comment: `if((a*x) % m == 1) return x;` must be the culprit. Are you sure you want to return before the cout?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable `x` really is local to the `for` loop, and can't be used outside of it.

Apparently G++ have an extension to allow usage of the "index" variable outside of the loop, but you have to add the `-fpermissive` flag to allow it. But do note that the `-fpermissive` flag also allows other things that's not "proper" C++.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problematic line:

```
cout <<"the value of x"<<x<<endl;
```

It's problematic because it uses the variable x outside the body of the for loop.

To fix the problem, either put the cout line inside the for loop, or declare the x value before the for line, rather than as part of it.